# unique column value in python numpy

Tags: python, numpy

my array is looking like this

```
a=np.array([[ 25,  29,  19,  93],
       [ 27,  59,  23,  345],
       [ 24,  426,  15,  593],
       [ 24,  87,  50.2, 139],
       [ 13,  86,  12.4, 139],
       [ 13,  25,  85, 142],
       [ 62,  62,  68.2, 182],
       [ 27,  25,  20, 150],
       [ 25,  53,  71, 1850],
       [ 64,  67,  21.1, 1570],
       [ 64,  57,  73, 1502]])
```

i want to return the lowest value of column 2 based on the unique value of column 0. column 0 should contain unique values.
I tries the following code, but was not giving me the exact result.
Can some one help me to sort out this? thanks

```
sidx = np.lexsort(a[:,[2,0]].T)
dx = np.append(np.flatnonzero(a[2:,0] >a[:-2,0]), a.shape[0]-1) 
result = a[sidx[idx]]
print result
```

I want to get result like

```
[25...
 27
 24
 13
 62
 64...]
```

```
a=[[196512 28978 Decimal('12.7805170314276')]
 [196512 34591 Decimal('12.8994111000000')]
 [196512 13078 Decimal('12.9135746000000')]
 [196641 114569 Decimal('12.9267705000000')]
 [196641 118910 Decimal('12.8983353775637')]
 [196641 100688 Decimal('12.9505091000000')]]this is a big list
i used,
df = pd.DataFrame(a)
df.columns = ['a','b','c']
df.index = df.a.astype(str) 
dd=df.groupby('a').min()['c']

but i am getting,

195556    12.7805170314276
195937    12.7805170314276
196149    12.7805170314276
196152    12.7805170314276
196155    12.7805170314276
196262    12.7805170314276
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an easy solution. The sort order changes, but that shouldn't be difficult to address if you really care:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(a)
df.columns = ['a','b','c','d']
df.index = df.a.astype(str) # to preserve correspondence
df.groupby('a').min()['b']

a
13.0    25.0
24.0    87.0
25.0    29.0
27.0    25.0
62.0    62.0
64.0    57.0
Name: b, dtype: float64
```

Edit: I think you meant to name your array `y` instead of `a`. This works for me:

```
 from decimal import Decimal

 y=np.array([[196512, 28978, Decimal('12.7805170314276')], 
    [196512, 34591, Decimal('12.8994111000000')] ,
    [196512, 13078, Decimal('12.9135746000000')] ,
    [196641, 114569, Decimal('12.9267705000000')] ,
    [196641, 118910, Decimal('12.8983353775637')] ,
    [196641, 100688, Decimal('12.9505091000000')]])


 df = pd.DataFrame(y) 
 df.columns = ['a','b','c'] 
 df.index = df.a.astype(str) 
 dd=df.groupby('a').min()['c'] 

In [210]: dd
Out[210]:
a
196512    12.7805170314276
196641    12.8983353775637
Name: c, dtype: object
```

Comment: when i changed the  dataframe to 3 column <pre>[[196512 28978 Decimal('12.7805170314276')]
 [196512 34591 Decimal('12.8994111000000')]
 [196512 13078 Decimal('12.9135746000000')]

 [196641 114569 Decimal('12.9267705000000')]
 [196641 118910 Decimal('12.8983353775637')]
 [196641 100688 Decimal('12.9505091000000')]]
</pre> it is resulting like <pre>195556    12.7805170314276
195937    12.7805170314276
196149    12.7805170314276
196152    12.7805170314276.....</pre> it is taking the minimum of that entire column value, not for the group min. it assign 12.7805170314276 for all column

Comment: Edit your post demonstrating a reproducible example of the issue you're having. I can't really tell what's going on in that comment.

Comment: reproducible. like your original post. Give me a data strucutre I can copy paste and a code chunk that causes the unwanted behavior you're experiencing.

Comment: I think you meant to name that array `y` instead of `a`, which will just give you: `196512    12.7805170314276
196641    12.8983353775637`

Comment: David i edited in the question, with code, can you check it.